# pivot query where data which is being pivoted contains same text

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

I'm pivoting data which contains name and phone numbers for some person records. The row which I'm pivoting contains questions which are: name, phone, name, phone. Yes, the questions are the same repeated text.

My pivot function is like so

```
SELECT 
        pesonnel_id,
        Qasked,
        Qanswered
FROM
       ....
pivot (max(QAnswered) for QAsked in ([Name], [Phone], [Name], [Phone])) p
```

Obviously, SQL does not like that ....it says [Name] was specified multiple times for p....hmmm, how do I get around this?

I do have a set number of the questions, it is just these 4 (name, phone, name, phone), so I don't mind 'hardcoding' something in, just don't know how/where.
I'm using SQL2012.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Sql server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some way of differentiating values of the pivoted column. You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` for this purpose:

```
SELECT pesonnel_id, [Name1], [Phone1], [Name2], [Phone2]       
FROM (
   SELECT pesonnel_id,
          QAnswered,
          QAsked + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pesonnel_id, QAsked ORDER BY QAnswered) AS varchar(50)) AS QAsked
   FROM #mytable ) src                      
PIVOT (MAX(QAnswered) FOR QAsked in ([Name1], [Phone1], [Name2], [Phone2])) p
```

You also, cannot use the column being aggregated, i.e. `QAnswered`, in the `SELECT` clause of the outer query.

Comment: Brilliant, it works. I'm going to study a bit more on partition by..... Never used it before. Thanks so much!